# There is no byte type in c. But I found byte type in programming

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to learn I2C from this website https://forum.dronebotworkshop.com/arduino/i2c-part-one-tutorial-and-slave-demo-sketch-for-platformio/. In the website section "Slave Demo Sketch" (Arduino), there is one line code that I don't understand.

What is type of Byte? What does the byte inside the brackets mean?

```
for (byte i=0; i<ANSWERSIZE; i++) {
  response[i] = (byte)answer.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: `byte` could be a `typedef` to e.g. `unsigned char`. Using a type inside `()` means **casting** the value following it to that type.

Comment: Which website are you referring to?

Comment: Most likely a defined type based upon `unsigned char`. It's quite common practice in embedded systems, you'll also come across `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` types and their signed equivalents. Typically, this is to ensure clarity on the data size whether compiling on an 8, 16 or 32 bit processor. In this case your `byte` will likely be 1-octet or 8bits in size.

Comment: `answer.charAt(i)`??? Is that a member function? Is this C++? Or is this just bad typing in the question posted here?

Comment: That [webpage](https://forum.dronebotworkshop.com/arduino/i2c-part-one-tutorial-and-slave-demo-sketch-for-platformio/) includes `Arduino.h`. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/byte/

Comment: @Fe2O3 "Slave Demo Sketch" is a hint. Those code fragments used for Arduino are called sketches. Arduino actually uses C++. But many users don't seem to be aware of that. But of course, you could also use a struct holding a function pointer in C as well... ;)

Comment: Arduino is C++ not C

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks. I've added a tag and the word "Arduino" to the text... Mind reading sometimes... thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, type naming is somewhat subjective, though wide consensus exists.

Various sketchy, home-brewed types tend to exist in some libraries. `byte`, `BYTE`, `U8` and other such non-standard types. These are almost always just some flavour of `typedef unsigned char slop;`, which is a completely useless `typedef`.

Some of the cornerstones of good programming practices:

- follow formal ISO standards or at least industry "de facto" standards and don't invent your personal non-standard
- don't complicate things just for the heck of it

Weird typedefs like `byte` go against both of these practices. In addition "I don't like typing" isn't a valid argument - programming is all about typing, those who don't like it or who can't figure out how copy/paste or code completion works picked the wrong trade. Besides, if you can't type `uint8_t` in around 1 second, it might be an indication that you need to practice typing on a keyboard way more, at least if you are serious about the programmer trade.

The only time when you should be using such non-standard types is when the existing code base is truly hellbent on using them and a lot of code like that has already been written. Using a different, although more correct type might just make the code more confusing at that point.

Good practice is to use the standardized types whenever possible, instead of inventing your own non-standard. Some rules of thumb of below:

Acceptable byte types:

- `uint8_t` (highly recommended)
- `unsigned char`

Acceptable boolean types:

- `bool` with `false` and `true` (highly recommended)
- `_Bool` with `false` and `true` (C only, not C++)

Answer (score 1):

If [this](https://forum.dronebotworkshop.com/arduino/i2c-part-one-tutorial-and-slave-demo-sketch-for-platformio/) is the demo you are referring to(which seems to be the case since it contains the snippet you posted). What you are describing is an Arduino [byte](https://arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/byte).

A version of the `Arduino.h` header can be found [here](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/Arduino.h) where byte is defined as `typedef uint8_t byte;`.

It is worth noting that Arduino is not C, it is C++(avr-g++).

Comment: That's one horrible header, do not use! In particular it directly violates the C and C++ standards by redefining things like `abs`. The `byte` and `boolean` typedefs are just plain weird, as is defining floating point constants with huge resolution, for the use on a bloody 8-bitter without FPU. Or defining `atexit` as a macro, for a freestanding system. And so on. Whoever wrote that header was seriously incompetent and should not be writing libraries. Arduino is a pox.

Comment: @Lundin I almost wouldn't believe you, but yep ``undefine stdlib's abs if encountered``, good heavens, what a horrible thing to have in a header file! You'd almost imagine it was malicious if you didn't put it down to incompetence

Comment: @Lundin in Arduino you basically have to use this header. It is as horrible as Arduino code is.

Comment: Seriously, I could write a whole essay about everything that's wrong with that header file. It's not just some 10-20 problems, there are far more.